# Reversing string of length 1 has some weirdness

Tags: python, string, slice, reverse

I am reversing a string in python though I don't want to reverse the complete string. I am using `str[::-1]` to reverse the string but excluding the last character.

For example: `string = '0123456789'` to be reversed to `string = '987654321'`.

However when the string length is 1 then problem arises with the reversing.

I simply used `string=string[len(string)-2::-1]`. It works fine for string having length greater than 1. But when string length is 1, python shows some weird results.

```
    w='0123456789'
    >>> w[len(w)-2::-1]
    =>'876543210'           #PERFECT
    >>> w[len(w)-2:0:-1]
    =>'87654321'            #PERFECT
    >>> w[len(w)-2:-1:-1]
    =>''                    #WHAT? - (1)
    >>> w[len(w)-2:-2:-1]
    =>''                    #WHAT? - (2)
    >>> w[len(w)-2:-3:-1] 
    =>'8'                   #WHAT? - (3)
    >>> w[len(w)-2:-4:-1]
    =>'87'                  #WHAT? - (4)
    #now see what happens when length of w is 1
    >>> w='a'
    >>> w[len(w)-2::-1]
    =>'a'                    #WHAT - (5) as len(w)-2 is -1 
    >>> w[len(w)-2:0:-1]
    =>''                     #PERFECT
    >>> w[len(w)-2:-1:-1]
    =>''                     #PERFECT as it's [-1:-1:-1]
    >>> w[len(w)-2:-2:-1]
    =>'a'                    #WHAT - (6)
    >>> w[len(w)-2:-3:-1]
    =>'a'                    #WHAT - (7)
    >>> w[len(w)-2:-4:-1]
    =>'a'                    #WHAT - (8)
```

when `w='0123456789'` why are the lines marked `WHAT - (1)` and `WHAT - (2)` not showing anything while the lines marked `WHAT- (3)` and `WHAT - (4)` start from 8 in reverse direction? When `w='a'` why are the lines marked `WHAT - (5)` shows `'a'` when I am starting from -1 index and what is happening with the lines marked `WHAT - (6)`, `WHAT - (7)` and `WHAT - (8)`?

Comment: Forget about reversing for now.  Try this: `'a'[-1:-1]`.  Or heck, even `'a'[0:0]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**w = '0123456789'**

The index can be read as "from where (inclusive)":"to where (exclusive)":"step size". Negative elements in the first two sections imply a `+ len(...)`, so something like `w[len(w)-2:-1:-1]` is equivalent to `w[-2:-1:-1]` or `w[-2:len(w)-1:-1]`.

Given `len(w) == 10`, `w[len(w)-2:-1:-1]` means `w[8:9:-1]`. This is obviously empty, since you can't get from 8 to 9 going backwards.

`w[-2:-2:-1]` is empty for the same reason (just as `w[2:2]` would be, for example).

`w[len(w)-2:-3:-1]` is `w[8:7:-1]`, which is just a single character, `'8'`, as expected. Similar reasoning for `w[len(w)-2:-4:-1]` mapping to `w[8:6:-1]`.

**w = 'a'**

To explain `w[len(w)-2::-1]`, you need one more piece of information: an empty start or stop index means "the limit in the appropriate direction, including the sign of the step size". So a missing stop index with a step of `-1` means "past the beginning of the sequence". Also, keep in mind that `len(w)-2` is `-1` in this case. So you have `w[-1::-1]`, which means go from the last element to the beginning backwards, i.e., `'a'`.

`w[len(w)-2:-2:-1]` is simple if you keep track of indices as well: `w[-1:-2:-1]` is pretty much exactly equivalent to `1[-1::-1]` when the length is 1.

The larger negative stop indices should be straightforward. There are no elements past the beginning of the string, so the result is always just `'a'`.

You'd see more expected results if your start index was `len(w)-3` or so, since in this case the `len(w)` just confuses the issue.

Comment: i didn't understand this line (correct me if i'm wrong)  <<<<< w[len(w)-2:-2:-1] is simple if you keep track of indices as well: w[-1:-2:-1] is pretty much exactly equivalent to 1[-2::-1] when the length is 1.     >>>>>   I checked in IDE and both are not the same - w[-2::-1] gives an empty string while w[-1:-2:-1] gives the only character present in single length array. OR IF YOU WERE TRYING TO SAY SOMETHING ELSE, PLEASE CLARIFY. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Pera. Thanks for the catch. Fixed the typo.

Comment: oh! I got it now. Thanks! 

Comment: @Pera. "-1" means the last element, "-2" means the second to last, etc. So `-1:-2:-1` effectively means start from the last element, and go past the beginning of the string (if the string only has one element). `-1::-1` means the same thing.

Comment: actually now i noticed the typo and understood what you have said. Yes it makes sense. 